# "E: Package 'gs' has no installation candidate" for mindtouch installation

Tags: 12.04

I am following the instructions on this site [Installing Mindtouch on Ubuntu](http://developer.mindtouch.com/Official_Mindtouch_Deki_Community_Edition_Installation_Guides/Ubuntu_8.04_MindTouch_Deki_Community_Edition_Package_Installation).

At the part where I am asked to install dependencies packages, `apt-get install html2ps poppler-utils html2text wv gs tidy links msttcorefonts cabextract mysql-server`, I met with the error `E: Package 'gs' has no installation candidate` and I have no idea how to resolve it.

I have since went to download relevant gs .deb file, get upgrade, installed synaptic package manager, but none of the steps helped. I am also pretty sure that my gs file is located under `/usr/bin/` as I physically went to search for it. Anyone can help me with this issue? I would be very grateful.

This is the relevant part:

```
machine@machine-ProLiant-MicroServer:/usr/bin$ sudo  apt-get install html2ps poppler-utils html2text wv gs tidy links msttcorefonts cabextract mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'ttf-mscorefonts-installer' instead of 'msttcorefonts'
Package gs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'gs' has no installation candidate**
```

PS: I am using ubuntu 12.04 if this information helps.

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions are very outdated. [Mindtouch](http://www.mindtouch.com/about/) transitioned from an open source project to a commercial product several years ago.

You can download a free trial from the above link.

You can download the source of an older version from [Mindtouch at SourcForege](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dekiwiki/files/?source=navbar). Development of this version seems to have mostly stopped a few years ago, but some of the files have recent dates so maybe there has been some minor updating.

Comment: @user168124 If it helped you, please upvote or accept the answer. :)